# No puedo sacar el promedio en mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo esta consulta

```
select resultados.idFuncionario, resultados.idEvaluador, avg(resultados.valor), competencia.id from resultados, competencia, funcionario, nucleo
where resultados.idEvaluador = funcionario.id and resultados.nucleo = nucleo.id and nucleo.idCompetencia = competencia.id
order by  resultados.idFuncionario, competencia.id
```

Pero me saca el promedio de todo el resultado la idea es sacar el promedio de resultados.valor por cada competencia.id, no lo puedo lograr en que fallo? en el order by?

Comment: Te falta el `GROUP BY`

Comment: Para más detalle: `group by resultados.idFuncionario, resultados.idEvaluador, competencia.id`

Comment: Cuando usas una función de agregación como:

* `sum()`
* `avg()`
* `max()`
* `min()`

etc

Estas realizan las operaciones y agregan en una sola fila como resultado el calculo generado de acuerdo a la que fue invocada.

Entonces a tu consulta le hace falta el `GROUP BY()` para indicarle que de los resultados calculados, usarás varias columnas para agrupar y mostrar el concentrado de resultados por grupos

Comment: `group by columna1, columna2, n...`